# Excel format to improper fraction OR integer

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am currently using custom formatting to get an improper fraction (###/###), however, I will need the integers to be 7 instead of 7/1. How do I achieve both improper fraction OR integer (if it can be simplified)?

[image: improper fraction]

Comment: Perhaps use conditional formatting and test whether the cell value = INT(cell value).  Use the result to pick which format to apply.

Comment: As in do a conditional formatting to highlight the integers and manually replace them?

Comment: Not to highlight, just to select the specific formatting you want (integer vs. fraction).

Answer (score 1):

I use : `=IF(INT(C2)=C2,TEXT(C2,"#"),TEXT(C2,"###/###"))` and drag downwards.

Seems to solve it just fine. Hope it helps. ( :